# How do I find the logs of Firefox?

Tags: debugging, firefox

While browsing the Firefox source code, I see that a lot of logs are present. I'd like to find them on runtime to help me understand and debug something.

For example, when taking a look at [nsHttpConnection.cpp](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpTransaction.cpp#l1724), Here's what I can find :

```
  ...
  LOG(("restarting transaction @%p\n", this));
  mTunnelProvider = nullptr;
  ...
```

Where did the LOG lines go ? How do I find the log file containing all the logs generated by Firefox ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of the file [nsHttpConnection.cpp](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpConnection.cpp), the `LOG()` functions are macros defined in [HttpLog.h](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/netwerk/protocol/http/HttpLog.h).

here's an excerpt :

```c
#define LOG1(args) \
  MOZ_LOG(mozilla::net::gHttpLog, mozilla::LogLevel::Error, args)
```

You can see them as shortcuts for the more complete `MOZ_LOG` functions.

- `LOG1()` -> Error
- `LOG2()` -> Warning
- `LOG3()` -> Info
- `LOG()` = `LOG4()` -> Debug
- `LOG5()` -> Verbose

If you want to get the logs for the `nsHttp` module, you can set 2 environment variables, and then run firefox :

```
set MOZ_LOG=nsHttp:5
set MOZ_LOG_FILE=http.log
firefox
```

or run firefox with the command line parameters :

```
firefox -MOZ_LOG=nsHttp:5 -MOZ_LOG_FILE=nsHttp.log
```

This enables Verbose level information (and higher) and places all output in the file `nsHttp.log`.

The `MOZ_LOG` variable is composed of as `<module>`:`level`.

You can also use a more general module `all` to include them all.

i.e. to log all Error level informations in the file `all.log`:

```
firefox -MOZ_LOG=all:1 -MOZ_LOG_FILE=all.log
```

For more information on how the `MOZ_LOG` variable is configured, you can take a look at [prlog.h](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/nsprpub/pr/include/prlog.h)